# Height can not be changed when using Dispay:flex

Tags: html, ios, css, flexbox, display

Hi I am new to flex and just was doing something to get acquainted. It works great when on Desktop ratio but is messed up on mobile.

http://s.codepen.io/nikasv/debug/VjxLJL

p1 and p2 should have a min-height of 150px and 100px respectively(and p3 should fill rest of the height). It seem that it doesn't work tried removing min-height and/or adding them but just always seems like the height is the same for all three containers. this bugs is very visible on iPhones 5 and 6.

Please help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H87Xr.png

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: well, dev tools say the middle div height is set to 100%

Comment: And the left area need sfixing, you can do this with the ordinal group property. or just display then all stacked as column on mobile devices.